# Is it possible to make a mathematical function generator using Arduino?

Tags: analogwrite, digital-analog-conversion

I want to build a function generator but not the ones which outputs square wave or sawtooth ect. I will input a discrete function lets say f(n) = e^n for n=0 to n=100 and the output array will be outputs as voltage samples creating a e^x like signal on a scope?

Is this possible?

Comment: If you attach some kind of DAC to it - why not?

Comment: but doesnt Arduino have already its own DAC?

Comment: No, why would it? Before assuming something, check the specs.

Comment: sorry Im not into micro controllers much. Isnt Arduino's analog output a DAC? if not whats that?

Comment: If you refer the `analogWrite` function - it is setting PWM output.

Comment: oh ok now I got it thanks. what would you recommend as a DAC converter in this case? im not into DAC hardware.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate arbitrary waveforms using either the built-in PWM and a low-pass filter or an external DAC.

You won't get more than 16-bits in PWM ( or AFAIK non-audio DAC with arduino libraries ), so your e^N function will be below your resolution for most of the cycle.

Alternatively, generate a saw-tooth and use an [op-amp exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Exponential_output)

Comment: no I just gave an e^n as an example. I want to make one which can output any given simple function.

Comment: You can't generate arbitrary waveform using PWM, unless you have some kind of PWM-to-waveform circuitry. And the bitness of DAC is depending on DAC only, and can be as high as specified by the DAC itself.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Add an appropriate low pass filter and PWM becomes a low-quality DAC.  If you can find a greater than 16 bit, non-audio, DAC with an arduino library, post a link.

Comment: I would say that you CAN generate arbitrary waveforms using PWM. All you need is a reconstruction filter. All 1 bit DA (sigma delta) converters basically use PWM. BUT the PWM signal from an Arduino is very low in frequency (around 400 Hz) and only 256 levels (8 bit) so very crude. You could make a half decent 10 Hz arbitrary waveform though. But note the 10 Hz, not very usefull !

Comment: Filter = circuitry. Why audio is a constraint?

Comment: Audio DACs are usually limited to a sample rate of around 200 kHz. It could be sufficient depending on what arbitrary frequency you want to generate.

Comment: whats the thing anout 16 bit? why ui that a limit?

Comment: Perhaps it's not easy (or impossible?) to find any off-the shelf gen purpose DAC with higher than 16-bits resolution. But here is an App note of a 20-bit DAC concept: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an86f.pdf

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think the average Arduino user has enough of a challenge to a 12 or at best a 14 bit DAC to its rated spec, higher resolution DACs are just more expensive. 20 and even 16 bit DAC's are a healthy challenge for EE pro's, let alone for hobbyists.

Comment: @jippie I agree. Just theorizing :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. As long as, in your theorising, you realise that Arduino level hardware is generally not going to outperform a 5mV to 10mV noise figure. So anything beyond 12bit with +/-5LSB accuracy at 5V reference is wasted money anyway.

Comment: @Asmyldof Why should I care of Arduino hardware, if I have some kind of I2C controlled DAC?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Because the comment was towards "Arduino level Hardware". If the OP is going to buy a DAC board ("not really into DAC hardware") and hook it up in the general way, that'll easily be 10mV coupled noise, if not more.

Comment: @user16307 PWM on ATMega uses the timers, the highest resolution one being 16 bit. As the others have noted, you probably will hit noise issues before then, but the point was more that when thinking about generating such-and-such a waveform, if a 16 bit DAC won't give you anything 90% of the time, your waveform is probably not realistic on any home-made hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Arduino DUE has a built-in DAC (has two in fact) and so you can do arbitrary function generation fairly easily by just going over some arbitrary table (that sampled the function) and output that with [`analogWrite`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite) to the DAC channel[s]; details in [this arduino.cc tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DueSimpleWaveformGenerator). They only show sine/triangle/square waves there, but if you look at Waveforms.h at the end of that tutorial you can put arbitrary shapes in there.

By the way this technique of waveform generation of using a lookup table and a DAC is abbreviated DDS for [Direct Digital Synthesizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesizer).
Here's a more conceptual tutorial on DDS (not involving arduino):
http://www.ni.com/white-paper/5516/en/

The DACs built-in Arduino DUE have 12-bit resolution by the way, i.e. 4096 discrete output levels. IF you need better than that, an external DAC is required, which you could connect by TWI/SPI etc.

You can get a poor man's DAC on the Arduino UNO or Leonardo by PWMing with `analogWrite` on the GPIO pins (as suggested in the other answer), but you need [understand low pass filter fundamentals](http://provideyourown.com/2011/analogwrite-convert-pwm-to-voltage/) to get that done.

Comment: ... or create an R-2R ladder on any number of IO pins you want.

Comment: @Majenko: yes, that can surely can be done but it can well turn into a project by itself: e.g http://pcarduino.blogspot.com/2013/11/arduino-r-2r-ladder-audio-dac.html